# Testing whether two ordered sequences could have been drawn from the same distribution

Tags: categorical-data

I have to compare multiple sequences (typical lengths 100-400 elements) drawn from the same limited set of elements (typically 2-6 different ones). These sequences can have different lengths. I need to find out whether these sequences could have been drawn from the same distribution functions (normalized to the sequence length). Below is an example of such a distribution function for one element in such a sequence.

In this case, I use the term distribution function as follows: It describes the expected value for observing an element at a specific position in the sequence, where the position is normalized to the number of elements of the sequence.

The sequences are formed by sequential addition of elements from a reservoir to an existing sequence. The addition of a new element depends on the last element in the sequence and the composition of the reservoir. Since the last element can influence which element is added next, this may lead to the formation of multiple different sequence populations. For example in the extreme case of two elements A and B, and B **never** follows A, then we will get sequences of only B and sequences with a (small) block of A and then a block of B. I need to know if different populations form and what their element distributions look like.

I am currently facing the situation that I have the sequences, but I do not know the distribution from which each sequence was drawn. Hence I need a test that allows me to group sequences together that could have been drawn from the same parent distribution. I came across the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for testing whether different sample sets could have drawn from a specific distribution, however, I do not think this test is appropriate for this situation.

What would be a statistically sound way to find out whether two sequences (possibly of different length) could have been drawn from the same distribution?

[image: Example distribution function]

Comment: Why would the progressions of frequencies be similar if the initial frequencies are not? There might be a good argument about that for DNA, but the post so avoids any scientific context that it’s hard to provide any useful statistical suggestions. (The KS test is useful for cumulative distributive functions, as in the tag, but that tag doesn’t fit the description of the situation.)

Comment: It is almost always more constructive to explain your *problem* rather than go into details about an attempted *solution* that might or might not work.  Your first paragraph is a good start, but the rest seems like it's going off in a direction that might be fruitless or even misleading.

Comment: I have updated my problem description, though I am not sure of the tags. Feel free to update the tag to a more appropriate category.

Comment: Could you explain why the KS test might not be appropriate?  Based on what you have described, it sounds perfect.  I would guess you are harboring some unexpressed assumptions about lack of independence of the values in each sequence, but it's difficult to determine what form that might take.  Alternatively, you might be using the term "distribution" in a sense different from that ordinarily understood in statistics, so consider offering a definition.

Comment: It sounds like a two-sample distribution test, such as Kolmogorov-Smirnov, is getting at what you want to do. If that is not the case, could you please explain what KS does not do that you want it to do?

Comment: Maybe I use the term distribution function different from common usage in statistics. In my case it referce to the distribution of the elements over the positions in the sequence. I have updated this in my problem description as well.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  You appear to be describing a kind of *stochastic process.*  It's still hard to tell *what* properties of these processes you want to compare.  The more you can tell us about its statistical characteristics, the better able we will be to help.

Comment: I added some clarification to the original question. I am trying to compare the distribution of the elements along the length of the sequence in order to be able to normalize the sequences in a population and estimate the distribution function of this population using an average expectation value along the normalized length coordinate of the sequence.

Comment: Could you please explain what kind of quantity an "element" might be? The graph suggests it might be some kind of number, but this does not accord with your description.  You really will be better off disclosing your application rather than trying to describe it abstractly, because you're unlikely to capture the important aspects of your problem (unless you fully understand it--but then you wouldn't be asking about it!).

Comment: A simple analogy would be building a tower with lego. The elements would then be different color blocks and the sequence would be the resulting tower. The graph refers to the observation frequency of one element at a normalized position in the sequence. For instance, in a sequence of 100 elements, element number 20 has 80% chance of being a red brick, while element 70 only has 20% chance of being red.

Comment: That graph, then, captures only a tiny bit of the relevant information.  I am beginning to suspect a simple permutation test might solve your problem, or possibly clustering based on a form of edit distance, or maybe a form of DTW, *etc.*; but from your abstract descriptions I just have no way of knowing how relevant any of this might be or how exactly it should be applied.

Comment: This would be clearer with a description of a model rather than a distribution, e.g.: “A model of sequence generation uses bases of 5 types, with known affinities, and reservoirs of 500 bases each. Sequences start with a random draw from a reservoir, and then take further draws whose probability of type T is proportional to the number of T’s left in that reservoir, times the affinity of T with the last draw. Given 100 sequences of different lengths, how can I estimate which ones came from the same reservoir?”